# Looking for an Image Comparison/Pattern Recognition Library

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, image-manipulation, pattern-recognition

The end goal would be to see if

[image: image1]

contains

[image: image2].

the compare needs to support minor distortion, scaling, color differences, rotation, and brightness differences.

it can be in any language really. i will be running this algorithm as a webservice so its no problem if i have to write this portion in c, c++, python, etc.

Comment: This is a lot more difficult than image comparison; this is pattern recognition. See http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/CVonline/recog.htm

Comment: This looks like a research-grade problem. I doubt you'll find a library that can do this out of the box.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should probably take a look at [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com) and [VLfeat](http://www.vlfeat.org).

Answer (score 1):

Object detection can be performed for example using

- **[Rapidminer IMMI](http://spl.utko.feec.vutbr.cz/en/component/content/article/46-image-processing-extension-for-rapidminer-5)** (image mining extension for one of the leading open-source data-mining platform)
- **[BoofCV](http://boofcv.org/index.php?title=Main_Page)** (using SURF feature detection)

Answer (score 0):

How about [**ImageMagick**](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php)? Its not a library per se however if you can provide shell access to your environment its pretty easy to use.

You would most probably be interested in the [**compare**](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/compare.php) command.

**EDIT:** ImageMagick does contain tools for sub-image search like [**subimage-search**](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?ImageMagick=vocn44la35ikp71p6efdfot286#subimage-search).

Comment: `compare` would not be able to tell if an image *contains* an image but would help if an image *is* an image.

Comment: The title reads "looking for an image **comparison** library". ImageMagick offers image comparison ability.

Comment: And there's also an entire question that specifically details the requirements (which ImageMagick compare do not meet)

Comment: thanks for the answer, looking it over now.  compare does have the option of a [sub-image](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?ImageMagick=vocn44la35ikp71p6efdfot286#subimage-search) search.  would this not work?  maybe run an edge-detection algorithm on the original image before searching for the sub-image?

Comment: That was the idea. You pick the tool you need from ImageMagick because its an image manipulation suite not a single tool. I have chosen **compare** because I thought you were actually searching for a way to compare two images (the title made me just fly over your question) but there are a lot of alternative tasks (commands) you can use to manipulate images.

Comment: Given the metrics available in compare, it is unlikely to be robust, especially if there is a scale change - as in the example pair of images. It does depend a lot on the types of images being searched for. I would have thought an edge detection filter would not be helpful.

Comment: Yikes! `subimage-search` compares the images at every possible relative position. You end up taking a 2D convolution of the images, which is spectacularly slow :(

Answer (score 0):

Look at this - http://gallery.azureml.net/MachineLearningAPI/02ce55bbc0ab4fea9422fe019995c02f - it supports OCR. This also supports multiple languages and distortion - http://www.projectoxford.ai/doc/vision/OCR