# Swift Straight Edge Detection of Live Camera Feed for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, core-image

I have a need to detect straight lines in an image. I know the straight lines will form a cross somewhere on my image, and I need to find those.

I would like to real time detect this cross and circle it on the screen while the user points his camera at it. So basically, I need to know where it is on the screen.

My question is with regard to Core Image or any other framework that would help solve this issue. I have looked in ARKit (I don't need to move around in a virtual environment) and Core Image detection (I see I can find a rectangle, face, or barcode. Would the rectangle work? It's sort of a straight line if it is a very skinny rectangle).

I'm new to working with these frameworks for, and I was wondering what you would recommend as a tool to detect the straight lines that would form the cross. Can it be done in Core Image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [vision API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision) can detect all sorts of features, but what you are asking for is a custom symbol.  For that you are going to have to train your own ML model (as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30859824/use-azure-machine-learning-to-detect-symbol-within-an-image) stackoverflow thread).  You can then run your model over your image with [CoreML](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreml).